# How to get name from 2 two tables whose ID is stored in table 3 in sql

Tags: sql, join

I want to get the names in one column using ConcerenedId.

[image]

In this table (Ledger) ConcerenedId contains id of both customer and vendor,and i want to get their name.

here is the table (Customers)

[image]

and here is the table (Vendors)

[image]

here is what i had done

```
  select l.LedgerId,l.ConcernedId,l.Amount,v.Name,l.Type,c.Name from Ledgers l 
  left join Vendors v on l.ConcernedId=v.VendorId 
  left join Customers c on l.ConcernedId=c.CustomerId
```

and here is its output

[image]

Output should be like
[image]

Please help if anyone know how to fix it. Thanks

Comment: First please show us the data from the table Customers that is relevant  for this example, in other words show us the row where CustomerId = 14 in table Customers ? Then please share with us how the final output should look like for example where LedgerId is 1? And finaly share with us what database do you use ? Oracle, SQLServer, MySQL or something else...

Comment: hello @VBoka, its not CustomerId=14, its VendorId=14 as i showed you the screenshot of Vendors and Customers table

Comment: i edit my question to show the my expected output, hope its clear now.

Comment: Hi @TimeToCode, now all I need is the database you use ? Oracle, SQLServer , MySQL...

Comment: Do you (could you) have a Customer with Id=14 , or a Vendor with Id=70?  How does your app guard against that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you will get to your solution if your database is SQLServer:

```
select l.LedgerId
       , l.ConcernedId
       , l.Amount
       , ISNULL(v.Name, c.Name) Name
       , l.Type
from Ledgers l 
left join Vendors v on l.ConcernedId=v.VendorId 
left join Customers c on l.ConcernedId=c.CustomerId
```

You can use ISNULL function.

Here is a DEMO:

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2db0735b6e2918477bf2d65e916e0eef)

If you use some other database here you can check what function to use: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

Comment: @TimeToCode - Does Vendor have priority over Customer for all types?

Answer (score 1):

The standard function to use in SQL is `COALESCE()`:

```
COALECE(c.Name, v.Name) as Name
```

This should work in any database.

I recommend using this over bespoke functions such as `ISNULL()`.  There are some situations where `ISNULL()` has some performance advantage in SQL Server.  But the benefit would not affect for this code.

Comment: @TimeToCode . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?